# Traffic Control using Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: networking, linux

My router doesn't have bandwidth control per IP/MAC feature. I was wondering if there's a way to use my Raspberry Pi 3+ (that's already used as a pi-hole) to control the bandwidth for each IP/MAC in my network.

Is there a way to use the raspberry pi as a front to the router (using port forwarding or MiTM for ex) and then control the bandwidth of each device using the [Traffic Control](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) library ?

NB : This is my network that I 100% own.

Comment: *"Is there a way to use the raspberry pi as a front to the router"* -> It's going to be a substantial bottleneck, so much so you probably won't need to bother implementing traffic control.  Everything will be slowed down...

Comment: Are you talking about LAN traffic or Internet traffic?  If the first invest in a decent switch, if the latter then look at OpenWRT for the Pi with at least one extra USB Ethernet adapter but note I upvoted Goldilocks answer.  Look at your router and see if it supports quality of service - else save money and time and buy a box that lets you set rules. even if it’s cheap On off eBay and can be reflashed with dd-wrt or similar it will save you pain.  Given the cost a cheap mini-itx  board with two lan ports may well be cheaper.  Also are you sure you need shaping or is it a lan or site issue?